# how do i refere my textbox of type file from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, memorystream

Im trying to upload an image to the database but i im getting an error with object refernece not set to an instance of an object.

i have a textbox in the view and im using memorystream in the controller but i cant store the image to the memorystream.

i also have a model where have this property

```
public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
```

heres the code from the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Picture</legend>

         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file" })
        @*<input type="file" value="file" />*@
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</fieldset>
}
```

and this is the code from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

        var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `enctype attribute` your `form` element

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", 
    "Home", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { id = "form", enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```